# Using ajax o display image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Can someone help to fix this? When the images is directly added into the code it works. But when tried to retrieve the image path from the MySql using ajax, it doesn't work.

All I want is to make this line work:   **'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },**

This code works:

```
(function() {
    var image = { 
        'back': { 'url':'img/logo.jpg', 'img':null },
        'front': { 'url':'img/another.jpg', 'img':null }
    };
```

But this doesn't work though ajax sucessfully fetch the data from the mysql?

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'php/myphp.php',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
        var imageX   =   'img/'+response[0].img+'.jpg',
            groupX   =   response[0].team;
            var s = document.getElementById("CurrentVal"); 
            s.value = imageX; **///shows img/logo.jpg**     


}
});
(function() {
    var image = { 
        'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },
        'front': { 'url':'img/another.jpg', 'img':null }
    };
```

Comment: could you post the whole javascript codes from you html?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the imageX value inside of your bottom function?

If you intend to use imageX variable on your bottom function, it must have a different scope. You are declaring it inside ajax success.

Comment: Hi Andre... thanks. You are correct... It's not showing out of ajax success. How can I fix this?

Comment: You must declare the variable out and before all functions. So it become a global variable.

Comment: Write `var imageX` before your ajax funtion. Inside de success function only call it like this: `imagX = ...`

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are trying to do, but, in your second code snippet, `imageX` will not have been defined. I.e. in

```
(function() {
var image = { 
    'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },
    'front': { 'url':'img/another.jpg', 'img':null }
};

imageX
```

will be undefined, because you are trying to actually reference window.imageX. The imageX in the success callback is declared as a local variable. So a 'hack' would be to make imageX a global variable. However, there is probably a better way to achieve what you are trying to do, but I would need more info.

**EDIT**

Ok, so there are a few problems. First, in `setupCanvases`, you reference `image`, which is undefined. So a partial fix would be to change your code to

```
var image = null;
var imageX;
var groupX;
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:'php/nmyphp.php',
dataType:'json',
success: function(response){
    imageX   =   'img/'+response[0].tickNum+'.jpg',
    groupX   =   response[0].tickCdt;

image = { 
    'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },
    'front': { 'url':'img/secondImage.jpg', 'img':null }
};
    ...
```

However, this will not produce the desired result, as you will only be able to see the last image that was loaded. I assume this is not what you want. To really fix it, I think you need to change the `setupCanvases`. Also, there seem to be some syntax errors in the js Fiddle you posted. For example, there's a `*/` without a preceeding `/*`.

Finally, you never seem to call `loadImages`, which is the function that eventually calls `setupCanvases` to draw the image.

Comment: Thanks Kiran.  I'm retrieving a name of an image via php in to ajax (logo.jpg). This logo.jpg resides in img folder. I want to be able to use that variable name+path to load the image  at 'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },

Comment: Yes, I got that bit :) I meant more what the point of the anonymous function where you declare and define var image = ... was. As others suggested, you can either create your object from the ajax callback and then call the function that uses this object, or put the code that uses your 'image' object into the ajax success callback.

Comment: I have added into the ajax bit in to the function (as tomas.polach.ch suggested). But the image doesn't display...

Comment: Of course it wouldn't. As I commented, all that he did was create a local object. You now need to *use* that object ;) Otherwise it just goes out of scope once when the success callback returns (in the code snippet this would happen right after the declaration of var image ...). Please paste the full code (on js fiddle or here).

Comment: changed your example to something that should at least load one set of images. However, as I noted, the code would need more than this change to make it work for multiple sets of images. http://jsfiddle.net/WXcA8/

Answer (score 0):

you need to put it inside the callback function

```
(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'php/myphp.php',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){

        var imageX   =   'img/'+response[0].img+'.jpg',
            groupX   =   response[0].team;
            var s = document.getElementById("CurrentVal"); 
            s.value = imageX; **///shows img/logo.jpg**  

        var image = { 
            'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },
            'front': { 'url':'img/another.jpg', 'img':null }
        };

        // add an image
        $('<img>',{
            src: image.back.url
        }).appendTo('body')

        // or load it into an existing dom object
        $('#image').attr("src",image.back.url);

    }
});
```

Comment: This is not a solution, because now 'image' is a local variable, and nothing happens once you've defined it. What is missing from the original question is how the 'image' object is used later on. Without that information I don't think it's possible to suggest a solution.

Comment: Thanks... I did that and CurrentVal  shows the result. But the image doesn't load? Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, you need to show us how you are intending to use the image object :) Once you show that, we can tell you how to fix it ;)

Comment: you can add the image with:
$('<img>',{src:image.back.url}).appendTo('body')
or set the source of an existing dom-object:    
$('#image').attr("src",image.back.url)

just add this at the end of your callback function

Comment: please see my updated answer. it does load the image.

Comment: Thanks tomas... It does... but it's not doing what it was doing as 'back': { 'url':'img/logo.jpg', 'img':null },

Answer (score -1):

disable asynchronous in your ajax by adding "async: false".Declare imageX as global

```
var imageX; // declare global

$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:'php/myphp.php',
dataType:'json',
async: false, // disable async
success: function(response){
        imageX   =   'img/'+response[0].img+'.jpg';
        var  groupX   =   response[0].team;
        var s = document.getElementById("CurrentVal"); 
        s.value = imageX; **///shows img/logo.jpg**     


}
});

(function() {
var image = { 
    'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },
    'front': { 'url':'img/another.jpg', 'img':null }
};
```